# Получение координаты точки в PyQt5 и PyQtGraph

Tags: pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Вобщем есть проект на PyQt5 и PyQtGraph. Хотелось бы узнать как получить координаты графика по клику (график находится в QGraphicsView).

```
        plot = pg.PlotItem()
        plot.setAspectLocked(True)
        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.Plot_map.setScene(scene)
        plot_widget = pg.GraphicsView()
        plot_widget.setBackground('w')
        plot_widget.setCentralItem(plot)
        scene.addWidget(plot_widget)

        # Add image
        img = pg.ImageItem(Z, axisOrder='row-major')
        # plot.setXRange(self.x_min, self.x_max)
        # plot.setYRange(self.y_min, self.y_max)
        # plot.getViewBox().scaleBy((0.01, 0.01))
        plot.addItem(img)
        # Create color bar and have it control image levels
        cmap = pg.colormap.getFromMatplotlib(self.colorComboBox.currentText())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.